# OxyPlot - Is there any way to hide data points?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm using WPF and OxyPlot and I wanted to hide some points on a series... however this doesn't seem to be possible to my surprise! Am I missing something? I am iterating over a set of points on a series, and I'm concentrating on a specific region of the graph of the series where I want the data points outside that range to not display.

Comment: I don't know oxyplot, but couldn't you create somewow a subset of the points, and then you give this subset to oxyplot?

Comment: I could but that would entail create another series and hiding the original?.... I don't know how "neat" that is...